# Scheme for dynamic DB-Tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, model

I'm working on a platform that enables user studies. I need to create a model for "studies" and some number of iterations inside a study ("study-iterations").

**Basically the admin should be able to:**

- create a new study
- create study-iterations inside a study

**Example:**

Each study has the following params:

- Param 1
- Param 2
- Param 3
- Param 4

Now the admin has to choose which params should vary in each study-iteration.

Let's assume he chooses Param 1:
That means that Params 2-4 stay constantly for all study-iterations of this specific study.
Only Param 1 has to be specified for each study-iteration.

**The problem**

Because of the dynamic bahaviour of params (they could belong to "study" OR to "study-iteration") I'm struggeling with creating a convenient data model.

I'm using PHP and MySQL for this web platform.

**I thought about the following solutions:**

- Creating tables "user" and "user-iterations" dynamically (CREATE TABLE...)
- Creating corresponding VIEWS in DB
- only one table "Study" with all data and storing variable params in $_SESSION or a separate DB-Table "variable-params"

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Sounds like a classic many_to_many relationship, that requires a couple of lookup tables `studys_params` `iterations_params`

Comment: Ok, but if there are a lot of params I would need a lot of tables. (all possible combinations of them). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, the lookup tables link a param to a study, or a param to an iteration, so you would have 5 tables: studies, study-iterations, params, studies_params, and iterations_params.

Comment: I think I kinda catched the idea but not completely. Could you please specify the attributes of these 5 tables?